# Call from a code reference in Template Toolkit

Tags: perl, method-call, template-toolkit

I have a simple higher-order function that builds a message formatter.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub make_formatter {
    my $level = shift;
    return sub {
        my $message = shift;
        return "[$level] $message";
    }
}
```

I use it from Perl like that:

```
my $component_formatter = make_formatter('ComponentError');
print $component_formatter->('Hello') . "\n";
```

I want to use `make_formatter` from a Template Toolkit template. I have tried to do the following:

```
use Template;
use Template::Constants;

my $template = Template->new({
#   DEBUG => Template::Constants::DEBUG_ALL,
    VARIABLES => {
        make_formatter => make_formatter,
    }
});

my $template_str = "
[% my_formatter = make_formatter('MyFormatter') %]
<h1>[% my_formatter('Sample message') %]</h1>
";

$template->process(\$template_str);
```

The output of this script is:

```
$ perl test.pl 
Use of uninitialized value $level in concatenation (.) or string at test.pl line 10.


<h1>[] MyFormatter</h1>
```

Is it possible to call `my_formatter` using only Template Toolkit syntax ? Calling external Perl code that is not callable by default from Template Toolkit is not an option.

Comment: Note: in the `VARIABLES` parameter you call `make_formatter`, perhaps you meant to provide a reference to the sub here instead? I.e. `VARIABLES => { make_formatter => \&make_formatter }`

Comment: You may get away with it when you would change `make_formatter => make_formatter` to `make_formatter => &make_formatter`. You did assign to the `VARIABLES` hash the result of calling the function (without any arguments, hence `undef` or uninitialized), rather then storing the reference to the subroutine.

Answer (score 3):

First let me please point out that putting `use strict; use warnings;` at the beginning of your script is strongly advised.

If you do that for your snippet generating the $template,
you will get a `Bareword "make_formatter" not allowed while "strict subs" in use` error, which should help you determine this is not a useful notation.

Now if you call `make_formatter()` instead, this will output `<h1>[] MyFormatter</h1>`. This makes sense: your function returned the sub, which is called with 'MyFormatter' in your template ( and $level is undef, as you called make_formatter with no input ).

As Mr. Haegland pointed out,

```
my $template = Template->new({
VARIABLES => {
    make_formatter => \&make_formatter,
}
});
```

leads to the output I understand you want:

`<h1>[MyFormatter] Sample message</h1>`

\&make_formatter gives you a subroutine reference,
which in perl normally you could call using:
`my $ref = \&make_formatter; $ref->( 'Input' );`

This can then be called in the first line of your template,
returning another code ref, which is then called in your second line.

Hope this helps!